# Favoriting question increases reputation - even on owned quesiton!

Tags: bug, reputation, bookmarks

It's nice that, when someone favorite my question, my reputation increases.

But today, I Favorited my own question, and found my reputation increased!!!

If this is the way, then it'd be a way to do forgery about reputation. I would increase my reputation favoriting all my questions. But that wouldn't be ethical, right?

I don't know any logic behind this, but to stop this, we can put a checker there:

```
when (favorite_question) {
   $the_question = get_question_id();
   if ( the_logged_in_user == $the_question=>inquirer_id ) {
      do nothing with $reputation;
   } else {
      $reputation .= 5;
   }
```

Hope the question is not duplicate.

Comment: I just favorited this question. You didn't gain any rep. [meta-tag:status-norepro]

Comment: I think you are mistaken - favoriting questions does not gain reputation.

Comment: I don't see you earned any reputation by favoriting in [your reputation tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1743124/mayeenul-islam?tab=reputation) Can you give a sample question where you earned reputation for that

Comment: But the same thing happened in my StackOverflow account, if I'm not wrong. :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770312/how-to-achieve-chamfered-css-border-corners-rather-than-rounded-corners

Comment: Sorry but you are wrong, favorting a question will never increase your reputation.

Comment: I think, someone has upvoted your question and favorite and you think you got reputation by favoring a question.

Comment: Did you favorite the question at the same time as you accepted an answer? Keep in mind that accepting an answer to your own question increases reputation. Perhaps that explains your confusion?

Comment: "Did you favorite the question at the same time as you accepted an answer?" -yap. That can be happened. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Favorites do not incur any reputation.

Check [your reputation summary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1743124/mayeenul-islam?tab=reputation&sort=post) on your account, and your [full reputation audit](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation).

My best guess would be that you happened to get an upvote (on that question or perhaps a different one) at the same time that you noticed the favorite star, when in fact the reputation increase and favoriting were unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood something. Looks like you are [favoring your question and accepting the answer at the same time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178994/favoriting-question-increases-reputation-even-on-owned-quesiton#comment-540872). And you earn 2 reputation when you accept the answer.